# Aplicar un codigo a todos los archivos de un directorio

Tags: pandas, python-3.7

tengo un archivos con un formato desarreglado, genere un codigo que me arregla el formato de este archivo en extension .csv y lo exporta en xlsx. Ahora quiero hacer que todos los archivos .csv que se encuentre en un directorio pasen por el mismo codigo automaticamente sin necesidad de estarlo tecleando en el codigo.

Mi codigo es:

```
import pandas 

filename = 'Prueba.csv'
data = pandas.read_csv(filename, header=9)
print(data.shape)
print (data.head(50000000))
data.dropna()
data.drop(data.columns[data.columns.str.contains('unnamed',case = False)],axis = 1, inplace = True)
data.drop('NombreC Cliente', inplace=True, axis=1)
data = data[data[' Cliente'].notna()]
data = data.drop(data[(data[' Cliente']==' Cliente')].index)
data = data.drop(data[(data[' Cliente']=='*')].index)
print(data[' Cliente'].value_counts())
print(data)

datoexcel= pandas.ExcelWriter('Pruebaok.xlsx')
data.to_excel(datoexcel,index = False)
datoexcel.save()
print("Terminado")
```

Alguien me podria dar una idea de como realizarlo?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Cual es el problema que tuviste?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar una par de funciones, del modulo os.

Lo primero es:

```
import os
 
os.getcwd()                           # Te muestra el directorio en el cual te encuentras
>>> '/home/usuario'

os.chdir('/home/usuario/Descargas')   # Te permite cambiar de directorio

os.getcwd()                           # Como cambiaste de directorio te muestra la ruta en la cual ahora te encuentras
>>> '/home/usuario/Descargas'
```

Lo anterior es para ubicarte en el directorio donde tienes todos los archivos .csv
Ya ubicados en el directorio.

Puedes listar los archivos que se encuentran en ese directorio para esto puedes usar:

```
os.listdir(os.getcwd())          # os.listdir Muestra los archivos que estan en el directorio, el directorio lo pasas con os.getcwd()
```

Puedes crear una variable, donde guardes los nombres de los archivos .csv (se puede dar el caso que existan archivos con otras extensiones)

```
list_arch = []                            # Lista donde se guardaran los archivos que contengan .csv en su  nombre

for c in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if c.find(".csv") != -1:
        list_arch.append(c)
```

***Tu código seria algo asi:***

```
import os
     
os.getcwd()                               # Te muestra el directorio en el cual te encuentras

os.chdir('/home/usuario/Descargas') 

list_arch = []                            # Lista donde se guardaran los archivos que contengan .csv en su  nombre

for c in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):         # Busca los archivos que contengan .csv en su nombre y los guarda en list_arch
    if c.find(".csv") != -1:
        list_arch.append(c)


for c in list_arch:                       # Imprime los nombres de los archivos que contiene .csv en su nombre
    print(c)
```

Ahora que tienes una lista con los nombres de los archivos, lo puedes unir a tu codigo. Esta es una solución larga. Con pandas encontraras que es mas reducida y elegante.

Answer (score 0):

Usando pandas, necesitarias saber la ubicación de los archivos o ubicarte en la carpeta que los contiene, para ello usas:

```
import os
os.chdir('/home/usuario/Descargas')   # Te permite cambiar de directorio
```

Muestras todos los archivos contenidos en ese directorio con listdir() y los almacenas en list_arch:

```
list_arch = pd.Series( os.listdir(os.getcwd()) )  # os.listdir Muestra los archivos que estan en el directorio, el directorio lo pasas con os.getcwd(), lo guardas como una Serie de Pandas
```

Ya que tienes la lista de archivos, en list_arch, seleccionas unicamente los que tienen la extensión .csv, y los guardas en una variable temporal (arch_temp)

```
arch_temp = list_arch.str.find(".csv").map(lambda x: True if x>= 0 else False )
```

Guardas en la lista (list_arch), unicamente los archivos que contengan ".csv"
list_arch = list_arch[arch_temp]

***Y listo el código seria:***

```
import os
os.chdir('/home/usuario/Descargas')               # Te permite cambiar de directorio

list_arch = pd.Series( os.listdir(os.getcwd()) )  # os.listdir Muestra los archivos que estan en el directorio, el directorio lo pasas con os.getcwd(), lo guardas como una Serie de Pandas

# Buscas en la lista, los archivos que en su nombre contienen la secuencia ".csv"
arch_temp = list_arch.str.find(".csv").map(lambda x: True if x>= 0 else False )

list_arch = list_arch[arch_temp]                  # Indicas que solo quieres ver las columnas que tienen archivos con .csv en su nombre
```

En list_arch, tienes una lista (pandas.Series)  con los nombres de los archivos que contienen ".csv" en su nombre, puede usar esa lista para pasar cada nombre a tu programa.

***Resulta mas sencillo si conviertes tu programa en una función.***

```
import os
import pandas

def conversion(filename):
  data = pandas.read_csv(filename, header=9)
  print(data.shape)
  print (data.head(50000000))
  data.dropna()
  data.drop(data.columns[data.columns.str.contains('unnamed',case = False)],axis = 1, inplace = True)
  data.drop('NombreC Cliente', inplace=True, axis=1)
  data = data[data[' Cliente'].notna()]
  data = data.drop(data[(data[' Cliente']==' Cliente')].index)
  data = data.drop(data[(data[' Cliente']=='*')].index)
  print(data[' Cliente'].value_counts())
  print(data)

  datoexcel= pandas.ExcelWriter('{}.xlsx'.format( filename.replace('.csv', '') ))   # El nombre del archivo csv sera el nuevo nombre del archivo xlsx
  data.to_excel(datoexcel,index = False)
  datoexcel.save()



carpeta = '/home/usuario/Descargas'                # '/home/usuario/Descargas' lo debes cambiar por la ruta donde tienes tus archivos .csv (si usas windows: 'C:\\users\\usuario\\carpeta\\o_algo_asi')
os.chdir(carpeta)

list_arch = pd.Series( os.listdir(os.getcwd()) )

arch_temp = list_arch.str.find(".csv").map(lambda x: True if x>= 0 else False )

list_arch = list_arch[arch_temp]

for archivo in list_arch:
  conversion(archivo)
```